# I have the follow boxplots that I wish to add averages

Tags: graphics

I have the following boxplots:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [title = {Lengths of Amplification and Deletion Regions},ylabel =
        {$\log_{10}(\hbox{Length})$},
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2,3},
    xticklabels={Amplification, Deletion, Both},
    x tick label style={font=\footnotesize, text width=2.5cm, align=center}
    ]
    \addplot+[mark = *, mark options = {red},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=2.214844,
      lower quartile=3.608312,
      median=3.895478,
      average = 4.05,
      upper quartile=4.447298,
      upper whisker=4.666284
    }, color = red
    ] coordinates{(0,4.832228)(0,5.513942)(0,6.29165)(0,5.216712)(0,5.677036)(0,4.981995)(0,5.172095)},
    node at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{(average)},1),
    {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{average}}};
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {blue},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=3.508799,
      lower quartile=5.079821,
      median=5.481519,
      average=5.442438,
      upper quartile=5.971588,
      upper whisker=6.250831
    }, color = blue
    ] coordinates{(0,6.508115)(0,6.486354)(0,6.860059)(0,6.620663)(0,7.312391)(0,7.357306)(0,6.421694)
    (0,6.479597)(0,6.690945)(0,6.661593)(0,7.271025)(0,6.396931)(0,7.035161)(0,7.371248)(0,7.033689)
    (0,7.002645)(0,6.590617)(0,7.171933)(0,6.416259)},
    node at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{(average)},1),
    {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{average}}};
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {green},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=2.437751,
      lower quartile=3.334956,
      median=4.336029,
      average = 4.47,
      upper quartile=5.068459,
      upper whisker=5.265037
    }, color = green
    ] coordinates{(0,5.826492)(0,5.819791)(0,6.21436)},
    node at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{(average)},1),
    {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{average}}};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

I have had help from other community's members and I have read the pgfplots manual. However, I am stuck: I would like to print each average above the respective diamond. What am I doing wrong with my nodes? Thank you!

Comment: I think you forgot a semicolon somewhere. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There are syntax errors, several commas at the end of lines (after the `coordinates` specification and in the middle of the `node` statement.
- `\boxplotvalue{<key>}` expects the key without additional parentheses.
- `node[above]` places the node above the specified coordinate.
- `0.5` instead of `1` places the node in the middle in the `box plot` coordinate system.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [title = {Lengths of Amplification and Deletion Regions},ylabel =
        {$\log_{10}(\hbox{Length})$},
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2,3},
    xticklabels={Amplification, Deletion, Both},
    x tick label style={font=\footnotesize, text width=2.5cm, align=center}
    ]
    \addplot+[mark = *, mark options = {red},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=2.214844,
      lower quartile=3.608312,
      median=3.895478,
      average = 4.05,
      upper quartile=4.447298,
      upper whisker=4.666284
    }, color = red
    ]
    coordinates{(0,4.832228)(0,5.513942)(0,6.29165)(0,5.216712)(0,5.677036)(0,4.981995)(0,5.172095)}
    node[above] at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average}, .5)
    {\boxplotvalue{average}}
    ;
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {blue},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=3.508799,
      lower quartile=5.079821,
      median=5.481519,
      average=5.442438,
      upper quartile=5.971588,
      upper whisker=6.250831
    }, color = blue
    ]
    coordinates{(0,6.508115)(0,6.486354)(0,6.860059)(0,6.620663)(0,7.312391)(0,7.357306)(0,6.421694)
    (0,6.479597)(0,6.690945)(0,6.661593)(0,7.271025)(0,6.396931)(0,7.035161)(0,7.371248)(0,7.033689)
    (0,7.002645)(0,6.590617)(0,7.171933)(0,6.416259)}
    node[above] at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average}, .5)
    {\boxplotvalue{average}};
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {green},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=2.437751,
      lower quartile=3.334956,
      median=4.336029,
      average = 4.47,
      upper quartile=5.068459,
      upper whisker=5.265037
    }, color = green
    ] coordinates{(0,5.826492)(0,5.819791)(0,6.21436)}
    node[above] at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average}, .5)
    {\boxplotvalue{average}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]